# Why I got an error (name 'theme' is not defined) when I want to plot a bar-dot plot using bioinfokit?

Tags: python, plot

`When I use bioinfokit library to plot a bar-dot plot using python v 3.7, an error rise that you should define the theme.

```
import  pandas as pd
import bioinfokit
from bioinfokit import analys, visuz
df= pd.read_csv ('DATA_41.csv')`your text`
print(df) 
X = df.iloc[:,0:4]

visuz.stat.bardot(df=X, show= True, r= 500, dotsize= 20, colorbar=("#f2aa4cff","#e69a8dff",    "#adefd1ff", "#5b84b1ff"))


NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-fcfe16fe390e> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 print (X)
      8 
----> 9 visuz.stat.bardot(df=df, show= True, r= 500, dotsize= 20, colorbar=    ("#f2aa4cff","#e69a8dff", "#adefd1ff", "#5b84b1ff"))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bioinfokit/visuz.py in bardot(df, dim, bw, colorbar,         colordot, hbsize, r, ar, dotsize, valphabar, valphadot, markerdot, errorbar, show, ylm, axtickfontsize, axtickfontname, axlabelfontsize, axlabelfontname, yerrlw, yerrcw, axxlabel,     axylabel, figtype)
    723         if len(color_list_dot) == 1:
    724             color_list_dot = colordot*len(df.columns.to_numpy())
--> 725         if theme == 'dark':
    726             general.dark_bg()
    727         plt.subplots(figsize=dim)

NameError: name 'theme' is not defined`
```

Comment: I think the variable theme isn't declared anywhere so when you use it Python can't find it. In the source at `https://github.com/reneshbedre/bioinfokit/blob/master/bioinfokit/visuz.py`, `theme` is an argument of the `volcano` function.

Comment: Yes, theme doesn't not work in visuz.stat.Bardot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, by downgrading to the 2.0.1 version, it was solved.

```py
pip install bioinfokit==2.0.1
```

Comment: If you want to use the newest version, you can upgrade the module, then open visuz.py in the /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bioinfokit/ with a text editor. Search for "bardot" and in the function definition add ",theme=None" to the function input parameter list, save the file, and run your code. Maybe you need to reimport the module, too.